# Updating an object already serialized

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Let's say I have a class `MyClass`:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string PropB { get; set; }
    // ...
    [ProtoMember(12)]
    public string PropL { get; set; }
}
```

I've also got a `List<MyClass>` and the protobuf-net binary is deserialized into it. How do I update an instance of `MyClass` contained in the serialized file (which could contains hundreds or thousands of serialized `MyClass` objects) on the fly? I looked at some of the comments Marc has made on other questions and it seems like I need to use `Deserialize` and pass in the `MyClass` instance but the only method signature I see is

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(System.IO.Stream source)
```

Maybe I need to use Merge? I'm not really sure how I should use it tho.

```
public static T MergeWithLengthPrefix<T>(System.IO.Stream source, T instance, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle style)
```

I'm using protobuf-net v2.0.0.480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* like you want to update the **file** version of the object - is that correct? If so, that isn't possible without re-writing the file - it would be like asking "how do I update an element in the middle of an xml file" - pretty easy to do, but you need to re-write the entire file. Well, *technically* you could just re-write the stuff *after* the bit you want to change, but frankly the simplest option is probably: read then re-write.

If this is something you need to do *regularly*, and you need fast append, I would probably suggest (at your application level) a strategy that allows you to **replace** objects by simply appending a new version on the end - i.e. if you see a duplicated id, assume that **replaces** the earlier occurrence - however, that means your reads need to read through everything, so it might be an idea to re-base occasionally.

But the simplest answer, unless you need something fancy, would be:

- deserialize the contents into a list (or similar)
- make the changes you need
- serialize

Comment: Your suggested answer at the end is what I'm actually doing right now. I was more or less just wondering if I could do in-place updates to serialized objects in the file.